# how i can remove the linking toolbar from ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the ckeditor by removing the linking and uplinking control. How can I remove them.

can someone show me how i can do this without changing the config file. I need to do this from within my own js file.

I need to configure before the initialization and rendering on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need to know can be found at: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar

PS: [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=fckeditor+configure+toolbars#sclient=psy&hl=nl&safe=off&source=hp&q=ckeditor+configure+toolbars&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=1&biw=1277&bih=679&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&cad=b)

Comment: The same seems to apply for ckeditor. I just edited my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
FCKConfig.ToolbarSets["MyToolbarSet"] = [
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] // enumerate all buttons you need
];      


var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('MyTextArea');
        oFCKeditor.BasePath = '<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/fckeditor/") %>';
        oFCKeditor.ToolbarSet = "MyToolbarSet";
        oFCKeditor.Height = 300;
        oFCKeditor.Width = 700;
        oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea();
```